# Control how to write to text to spinners and lists on Android

Tags: android, adapter, spannablestring

I've written a custom adapter for a few spinners and list views for my program. Here is the code:

```
public static class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int fontsize;
    private int color;
    private Typeface typeface;
    private int bgcolor = Color.rgb(50, 50, 50);
    private int selectedColor = Color.rgb(50, 50, 50);
    private int selected = -1;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, Typeface tf, int colour, int fsize) {
        super(context, resource);
        fontsize = fsize;
        color = colour;
        typeface = tf;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int bg){
        bgcolor = bg;
    }

    public void setSelectedColor(int color){selectedColor = color;}

    public void setSelectedPos(int p){
        selected = p;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setTypeface(typeface);
        v.setTextSize(fontsize);
        v.setTextColor(color);
        if (position == selected) v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
        else v.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
        return v;
    }


    public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView)super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setTypeface(typeface);
        v.setTextSize(fontsize);
        v.setTextColor(color);
        v.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Now what I want to do is control how the text is actually set in the text view that I return. To be more specific I would like use a SpannableString Builder like I do in other ordinary textviews of my app. Like so:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder textstring = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    Aux.addText(textstring,cardInfo,Colors.White,Dim.TEXTSIZE_TEXTVIEW,Fonts.Normal);
    text.setText(textstring, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I would like to write like this each item of the adapter. Can this be done? I would appreaciate if anyone could tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd answer my own question, since I found the solution. The key was to passed the string list in the constructor and then return the view and dropdown view with the corresponding text added the spannable string builder. Here is my Custom Adapter:

```
  public static class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int fontsize;
    private int color;
    private Typeface typeface;
    private int bgcolor = Color.rgb(50, 50, 50);
    private int selectedColor = Color.rgb(50, 50, 50);
    private int selected = -1;
    private boolean setColor = false;
    private List<String> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, Typeface tf, int colour, int fsize, List<String> labels) {
        super(context, resource,labels);
        fontsize = fsize;
        color = colour;
        typeface = tf;
        data = labels;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int bg){
        bgcolor = bg;
        setColor = true;
    }

    public void setSelectedColor(int color){
        selectedColor = color;
        setColor = true;
    }

    public void setSelectedPos(int p){
        selected = p;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        SpannableStringBuilder texter = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        Aux.addText(texter,data.get(position),color,fontsize,typeface);
        if (v != null) {
            v.setText(texter, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            if (setColor) {
                if (position == selected) v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
                else v.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }


    public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView)super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        SpannableStringBuilder texter = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        Aux.addText(texter, data.get(position), color, fontsize, typeface);
        if (v != null) {
            v.setText(texter, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            if (setColor) {
                if (position == selected) v.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
                else v.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```